# borderStyle:'dashed' not working when borderWidthRight:0

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set dashed border on top and bottom. Dashed border doesnt work when i set `borderLeftWidth:0` and `borderRightWidth:0`. Even after setting borderRadius the issue isnt solved.

```
:{
  borderWidth:1,
  borderRadius:1,
  borderColor:'white',
  borderLeftWidth: 0,
  borderRightWidth: 0,
  borderStyle:'dashed'
 }
```

Comment: What color is your screen background?
Try setting borderColor to black.

Comment: background is white color.....still doesn't work after setting borderColor to black

Answer (score 0):

Change your `borderColor` to something other than your white background color and  set your `borderLeftWidth` and `borderRightWidth` to a value greater than 0; that is overriding your `borderWidth` of 1.

Comment: I am trying to get border only on top and bottom!